# Scala demultiplexing Array by multiple types

Tags: scala, dynamic, types, scala-collections

Let

```
val a: Array[Any] = Array(1,"a",2,3.12,"c")
```

How to obtain

```
val out = Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array(1,2), Array(3.12), Array("a","c"))
```

Comment: I'm curious about the use-case. How did you end up needing a `Array[Any]`?

Comment: Working with language.dynamics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val aInt = a.collect { case i: Int => i } 
val aDouble = a.collect { case d: Double => d }
val aString = a.collect { case s: String => s }
```

or more generally

```
def filterByType[A: scala.reflect.ClassTag](a: Array[Any]) =
  a.collect { case x: A => x }
```

Concerning your last update, you can group by the runtime class and get the values out:

```
a.groupBy(_.getClass).values.toArray
```

Comment: @enzyme, what's the expected outcome?

Comment: Types are not value, so what do you want to list? The class tags?